# rtl8723be network adapter not working properly(very low signal strength) after upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: networking, hp, realtek-wireless, 19.10, rtl8723be

I've been having this network adapter problem on my HP laptop earlier also, but the general fix([rtlwifi_new](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new)) suggested by many users used to solve my issue most of the time. Once I've downloaded the rtlwifi_new, the following codes used to work on 19.04 as a fix.

```
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

The above codes had to be rerun every time a new kernal update was pushed. But after updating to 19.10 yesterday, the fix is no longer working even though the code is not throwing any errors. Now I have to literally sit right next to my modem to get online. I'm not sure if I've provided enough information required to solve this issue. Do let me know if more info is necessary. Kindly help as I couldn't solve this on my own.

**EDIT**: All solutions I've encountered were for version 19.04 and before. Those fixes worked perfectly. But they don't seem to work on 19.10. Hence raising a new question for 19.10.

Comment: The attached answer is not working either :/ Did a reboot with both settings(ant_sel=1 and ant_sel=2)

Comment: anybody have any clue as to what's causing this?